# Load two instances of the same DLL in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, loadlibrary

Here's my problem: I would like to create two separate instances of the same DLL.

The following doesn't work because Handle1 and Handle2 will get the same address

```
  Handle1 := LoadLibrary('mydll.dll');
  Handle2 := LoadLibrary('mydll.dll');
```

The following works, but I have to make a copy of the DLL and rename it to something else (which seems a bit silly)

```
  Handle1 := LoadLibrary('mydll.dll');
  Handle2 := LoadLibrary('mydll2.dll');
```

Is there a way to have only one DLL file, but load several instances of it?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Does the DLL save some sort of internal state that you want two distinct copies of?

Comment: My guess is that the first attempt doesn't work because `LoadLibrary` will return an existing handle if the DLL is already open.

Comment: I have to go with Mason Wheeler and ask: what are you trying to achieve with that. If you would succeed (like in you second example) you end up with two times the same code in memory. For me that seems a bit silly, too.

Comment: @Mason and Uwe: having a 3th party dll that won't let you have multiple instances of the service it provides would be a good reason to want what Tom is asking for.

Comment: Mason and Uwe: Yes, the dll contain certain processed information from the database. The two dll's are connected to separate databases and have different information. I'm trying to exchange information between them

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's possible.

You'd have to write a .exe which loads the dll. Then you can span multiple processes (the .exe), and each will run its own instance of the dll. You'd have to use IPC (inter process communication) techniques to communicate with the .exes. Certainly doable, but not exactly a no-brainer.

Comment: This is the safest, and official, way to do it without resorting to lower level hacks.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with LoadLibrary because Windows checks whether the dll has already been loaded and will return the same handle again and again.

I have got some code that was originally meant to load a dll from a resource bound to the executable but I guess it would also be possible to do the same for a memory area which was filled with the content of a file. I can't see any reason why it would not work twice, but I have not tested it.

You can find it here:
http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/dzchart/utilities/dzLib/trunk/src/u_dzResourceDllLoader.pas?view=markup

It is part of my library dzlib which is available under the MPL.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP introduced side-by-side execution for Win32 DLL's ([these guys](http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs.htm) know a lot about it).

With a lot of hoops you can now:

- [load the same Win32 DLL from the same path into memory twice](http://gis.shandyba.com/archives/15-Same-DLL-loaded-twice.html)
- load different versions of the same DLL into memory

Comment: The example of loading the same dll twice does it by using COM for one instance and LoadLibrary for the other. Although interesting, it may not be very practical in this case.

Comment: @Lars: It is the only way that I found which works. So: define 'practical' if you really need it :-)