# EXE and DLL Loading shared DLL leads to Invalid Pointer Operation and hang on termination

Tags: delphi, dll, loadlibrary

I have an Executable project which uses another DLL project and loads it dynamically using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. On the other hand, I have another second DLL which is used by both the EXE and the first DLL, also using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. I have a common unit which wraps the shared DLL, and is used in both the EXE and first DLL.

The problem is that after the EXE has loaded this second DLL and its procedure addresses, and then the EXE loads the first DLL, then the first DLL also loads the second DLL again, so it gets loaded twice. The end result is, when the first DLL is unloaded from the EXE, it also unloads the second DLL - which was actually sharing the same instance - thus also unloading the instance known to the original EXE. This results in an `Invalid Pointer Operation` error on shutdown, because the second DLL was already unloaded (and it's trying to unload it again) as well as the EXE hanging in the background invisible (using one full processor core).

How do I make sure the second (shared) DLL isn't unloaded until only the EXE is terminated?

There are two ways I can see to accommodate for this.

**Solution 1**

Pass the `HMODULE` instance and each proc address into the first DLL when you load it, and use that instance instead of trying to load it again. However this DLL has a huge number of exported functions which need to be passed into each instance.

**Solution 2**

Add a conditional to the second DLL something like `IS_DLL` and if this conditional is defined, do not compile the freeing of the shared library. It *should* be safe to call `LoadLibrary` twice - the second time should re-use the first one.

```
{$IFNDEF IS_DLL}
FreeLibrary(FModule);
{$ENDIF}
```

I'm not sure the second solution is accurate to my assumptions, but it would be my preferred solution, since the first solution would be much more work (given the size and complexity of the DLLs). I've tried it and it works, I'm just not sure what possible issues there might be.

Comment: If you call `LoadLibrary` twice, you should have to call `FreeLibrary` twice before it gets unloaded. How have you confirmed that it's really unloaded after just the first time. Also, take a look at `SafeLoadLibrary`. I don't remember what problem it solves, but it might be helpful in this case.

Comment: @RobKennedy Well when I unload it the second time it gives this Invalid Pointer Operation (within the EXE) when trying to free the second shared DLL. It's also well documented that consecutive calls to `LoadLibrary` will continue re-using the same instance/handle.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, executables do not have to account for which dlls loads/unloads what dlls. A test case would be good.

Comment: It's safe to call `LoadLibrary` twice. You'll get different module handles each time. DLLs are reference counted. You've misdiagnosed the problem. Step through the DLL with the debugger to investigate further.

Comment: @Rob I did, and the handles produced by `LoadLibrary` within the EXE and the first DLL are the same handle. Refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675519/load-two-instances-of-the-same-dll-in-delphi?rq=1

Comment: @Jerry - if this was the way Windows worked... well, it wouldn't.  Think about it.  You *must* have misdiagnosed your problem.

Comment: @Rob The module handle has the value of the base address. So repeated calls to LoadLibrary return the same numeric value.

Comment: @Rob SafeLoadLibrary temporarily masks floating point exceptions in case their being unmasked leads to exceptions in DllMain.

Comment: This is an XY question with no code... since the question is about a solution to your `invalid pointer operation` and rather not `Can I call LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary more than once and why` then I think this question needs *either* some code (or an mvce), to be rephrased entirely, or to be closed.

Comment: If you're getting an invalid-pointer-operation exception, then that means something is freeing something that either doesn't belong to the same memory manager, has already been freed once before, or was never a valid pointer in the first place. Use the debugger to figure out what's being freed. With two DLLs and an EXE, note that you have *three* copies of the Delphi memory manager in play; none can free something allocated by another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make sure the second (shared) DLL isn't unloaded until only the EXE is terminated?

DLLs are managed by an internal reference count. Whenever you call `LoadLibrary` the reference count is increased. The first call to `LoadLibrary` loads the library and sets the reference count to one. Subsequent calls increment the reference count and return the same module handle. Calling `FreeLibrary` decrements the reference count. When it gets to zero the library is unloaded. Every call to `LoadLibrary` should be matched by another to `FreeLibrary`.

The documentation is very clear on all of this. From [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx):

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).

From [`FreeLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152.aspx):

> Frees the loaded dynamic-link library (DLL) module and, if necessary, decrements its reference count. When the reference count reaches zero, the module is unloaded from the address space of the calling process and the handle is no longer valid.

You can conclude from all of this that you have mis-diagnosed your problem. Neither of your two proposed "solutions" are needed. That's because whatever your problem is, it's not what you think it is. You simply need to call `LoadLibrary` and rely on the system to keep the module loaded so long as the reference count is positive.

- If the DLL is unloading, then that's because you called `FreeLibrary` and its reference count went to zero. If you want it to stay loaded, don't call `FreeLibrary` until you are done with it.
- If the DLL is not unloading then your problem is clearly not what you said it was.